# Swift UIText Field throwing nil error when multiple words entered

Tags: swift, uitextfield, mapkit, option-type

My program is using map and I have a UITextField where the user enters a search phrase, the map will then show annotations of the search results on the map.
The program works fine in the simulator, but when tested on my phone it throws an "nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error if I enter two works such as "dog park".  But the program won't throw the error on my phone if I just enter "dog" for example.  I have the delegate set up in the ViewDidLoad and all my outlets are properly linked.
I've searched here and tried fixing the problem to no avail, so I thought I'd ask and see if you guys notice what I'm missing.

Here's the function for the UITextLabel search:

```
@IBAction func searchField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let allAnnotations = self.mapView.annotations
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = textField.text!
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print("Error occured in search: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }else if response!.mapItems.count == 0{
            self.textField.text = "No matches found"
        }else{
            print("Matches found")
            for item in response!.mapItems{
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                annotation.subtitle = item.placemark.thoroughfare! + ", " + item.placemark.locality! + ", " + item.placemark.administrativeArea!
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    })
    sender.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?  You should consider unwrapping your optionals using `guard let` or `if let` instead of force-unwrapping with `!`.  This may help you understand where things are going wrong as well.

Comment: Tried that and it still threw the error.  Stepped through the code in the debugger and it throws the error after the line "self.mapView.addAnnotation".  What's really weird about it is that if you enter one word it's fine, but two and it throws an error.  Not to mention that it works perfect in simulator.

Comment: on which line you are getting error?

Comment: I mentioned the line in my comment above.

Comment: Solved it.  I added "loc: nearby" to the naturalLanguageQuery.  So it's now request.naturalLanguageQuery = textField.text! + " " + "loc: nearby"

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, but I'm skeptical whether that's really the root of the problem (because we never add that `loc: nearby` and have never had a problem with multiple word `MKLocalSearch` requests ... out of curiosity, where did you find that suggestion?). Having said that, it's not immediately obvious what the real problem is, but I would suggest (a) canceling prior search; (b) avoiding `!`; etc. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/c5eb636ebee7db1a39968e0224169a22.

Comment: I have it canceling out the prior search already in another area of code.  Tried avoiding using "!" but it's necessary for the .text!.  Also tried using guard and if let with response and I still got the nil error.  As I said before what kills me about it, is it works perfect in the simulator.  Only problem is when I run it on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking into this more I found an answer that doesn't require adding to the naturalLanguageQuery string.  The problem was the for loop was returning a null value.  Putting a guard let in for response solved it.

```
@IBAction func searchField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let allAnnotations = self.mapView.annotations
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = textField.text!
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print("Error occured in search: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }else if response!.mapItems.count == 0{
            self.textField.text = "No matches found"
        }else{
            print("Matches found")
            guard let response = response?.mapItems else { return }
            for item in response{
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                annotation.subtitle = item.placemark.thoroughfare! + ", " + item.placemark.locality! + ", " + item.placemark.administrativeArea!

                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    })
    sender.resignFirstResponder()
}
```